# How to fill the missing rows of Pandas DataFrame with zeros?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` which relates to the non-trivial part of data: `df.head()` spits

```
    item_cnt_month
ID  
2   0.441488
5   0.461178
6   0.262789
10  2.861585
14  3.616117
```

I know that the final DataFrame has to be of size 214200 and thus I want to put the missing IDs with corresponding `item_cnt_month` equal to zero . How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = df.reindex(np.arange(214200), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Works like a dream.